# Find surface area of cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$ between two planes $x+y-4=0, y-z+4=0$

Tags: calculus

Find surface area of cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$ between two planes $x+y-4=0, y-z+4=0$.

I drew the picture but I can't seem to figure out the way to start.. If someone could give me a hint on how to start it would mean a lot..

Comment: The surface area remains constant if you rotate the planes about the y axis.  So you could change the 2nd equation to $y+x+4 = 0$  Then the sizes of the cylinder are a constant 8 tall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your cylinder is along $y-$axis and radius is $1$, your parametrization should be

$x = \cos t, y, z = \sin t$

$z - 4 \leq y \leq 4 - x$

Also $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$

Now $|r'_y \times r'_t| = r = 1$ (in this case). You can check that.

Your integral to find surface area is $\iint |r_y \times r_t| \, dy \, dt$

Answer (score 1):

Projects everything on the yz plane and works as a solid of revolution. I think it is the first idea that comes to mind, I hope it helps you

Comment: What can I do because the figure is not symmetric? I am having a hard time when I have to project a figure into a plane...

Comment: I understand, but you can divide the solid into parts where they are symmetrical for example in half, there you will have parts where it is easier to project, that is, divide the solid into parts where it is symmetrical and easy to project, you calculate the area in those regions and finally the sums

Comment: In the case that you divide the solid you can project on the plane that suits you, for example a part in the xy plane and the rest in the yz plane for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate planes about the y axis to be parallel then the cylinder has a constant height of 8.  The sides are then $2 \pi r h = 16 \pi$.  The planes intersect at a $45^\circ$ angle so the top and bottom are $r1 \cdot r2 \cdot \pi = 1 \sqrt{2} \ pi$.

$$A = (16+2\sqrt{2}) \pi$$

Answer (score 1):

With cylindrical coordinates $x= r\cos \theta$ and $z=r \sin\theta$, the surface between the two planes can be integrated along the cross-section circle of radius $r=1$
$$A= \int_0^{2\pi} (y_2-y_1)\cdot 1\cdot d\theta=
 \int_0^{2\pi} ((4-\cos\theta )-(\sin\theta -4))d\theta=16\pi
$$